# Service cannot access data from another Service

Tags: angular8

Im currently having some trouble with Angular 8.
Im trying to build a web app where you can search for Users and as a response get all the Users that 
match your Search + the Posts of the first listed User. For this i created a Service called SearchService
which has the function onSearch for sending the search to the Backend.

```
onSearch(search: string){

this.http.get(URL + search.trim()).subscribe((searchResponse: {user: Array<Users>, userPosts: Array<Post>} => {
  this.searchArray = searchResponse
  this.searchSubject.next(searchResponse)
})
```

After this when i try to like the Post of the User i call this function from my PostService

```
onLikeOrDislikePost(like: boolean, postId: string, section: string) {
    const data = {
        id: postId,
        like: like,
    };
    this.http.post(URL + '/like-dislike/post', data).subscribe((response: Post) => {
        this.updatePosts(response, section)
    })
}
```

As you can see i then call my updatePosts  function which finds out where the Post is, so wether the Post is in the Profil section or in the Search section, which Index it has in the Array, and if its even in the Array or not. Its a function i also use for adding Posts etc. thats why it may seem a little much.

```
updatePosts(postToUpdate: Post, section: string) {
    let indexOfPost = -1;

    if(section === 'profil'){  

      this.dataService.userPosts.map((post, index) => {
        if(post._id === postToUpdate._id){
          indexOfPost = index;
          return
        }
      })

      if(indexOfPost !== -1){
        this.dataService.userPosts.splice(indexOfPost, 1, postToUpdate)
      } else {
        this.dataService.userPosts.splice(0, 0, postToUpdate)
      }

      this.dataService.userPostSubject.next(this.dataService.userPosts)

    } else if(section === 'search'){

      this.searchService.searchArray.posts.map((post, index) => {
        if(post._id === postToUpdate._id){
          indexOfPost = index;
          return
        }
      })

      if(indexOfPost !== -1){
        this.searchService.searchArray.posts.splice(indexOfPost, 1, postToUpdate)
      } else {
        this.searchService.searchArray.posts.splice(0, 0, postToUpdate)
      }

      this.searchService.searchSubject.next(this.searchService.searchArray)
    }
  }
```

My problem now is that even though everything works fine with the profil section, when the function goes to the search section it fails because this.searchService.searchArray is undefined even though I have set it with the onSearch function. I have already looked if I have injected the Service wrong but all my services are injected by root, furthermore have I looked up the other components where i use my searchService in with the debugger and everytime the this.searchservice.searchArray was defined.

Im thankful for every bit of help

Comment: Have you injected the searchService in PostService's constructor ?

Comment: Yes and the import is also correct